# PGO slower than static optimization (intel compiler)

Tags: c, optimization, icc

I am using Intel C Compiler for I-32A architecture.
When I compile my C program with the following options:

```
icl mytest.c /openmp /QxHost /fp:fast /fast
```

The test run takes 3.3s. Now I tried to use PGO, so I compiled with:

```
icl mytest.c /openmp /QxHost /fp:fast /fast /Qprof-gen
```

I then run the executable with my sample input 2-3 times and compile again with:

```
icl mytest.c /openmp /QxHost /fp:fast /fast /Qprof-use
```

Hoping it will take into account collected information. It in fact tells me it's using the .dyn files but resulting executable is slower (3.85s) than without Qprof-use and this is on exactly the same data the runs were performed (should be perfect for PGO).
I tried setting openmp threads to one, thinking it might mess with .dyn output but the result is the same - it's slower than simple compilation.

**My question is**: is it even theoretically possible or I am messing up PGO process somehow with the compiler options ?

Comment: `/Qpprof-use`? Is the second p supposed to be there?

Comment: just a typo; typing was faster than copy-pasting from the console :)

Answer (score 2):

A 3.3-second floating-point application isn't going to see benefit from profile-guided optimization. From my guess, you're doing some sort of raw data crunching, which is better suited to hand-coded assembly if you need raw FLOPs than it is to PGO.

PGO will not tell the compiler how to optimize your inner loop to remove branch delays and keep the pipeline full. It *may* tell it if your loop is likely to run only 5,000 times or if your floats satisfy some criteria.

It is used with data that is statistically representative of other data you want it to run on. In other words you use it with data on a program that you want to be able to run other data with at a good clip. It doesn't necessarily optimize for the program at hand and, as you said, may even slow it down a bit for a possible net gain.

It really depends on your program but an OpenMP FP app is not what PGO is for. Like everything else it isn't a "magic bullet."

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I am still surprised it gives worse result for EXACT SAME data the profile runs were run on. Is there some explanation for this ?

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz Yes. Like I said it may determine your loop will usually terminate after 5,000 iterations. If it does that, it will add code to check for termination conditions around 5,000 iterations. It will basically add heuristics that will speed up the average predicted case, not necessarily the case you are definitely running, like how qsort performance is amortized. The loop thing is just a trivial example, by the way.